# Generate quey on doctrine querybuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-4.4

I have three entities `Compound`, `ComponentQuantity`, and `Component` the `Compound` has a `ManyToMany` relationship with `ComponentQuantity` and `ComponentQuantity` has a `ManyToMany` relationship with `Component`.

I need to get the `Compound`'s which `ComponentQuantity`  are related with a  `Component`,

If I would need the component quantity I would use:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("c")
            ->where(':componentQuantity MEMBER OF c.componentQuantities')
            ->setParameters(array('componentQuantity' => $componentQuantity));
```

but I need something like

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("c")
            ->where(':component MEMBER OF c.componentQuantities.components')
            ->setParameters(array('component' => $component));
```

but this not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `MEMBER OF` on a level so for example `c.componentQuantities` but not `c.componentQuantities.components`. To do this you would need to do this (make a join to get the data at the right level):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("c")
           ->join('c.componentQuantities', 'cq')
           ->where(':component MEMBER OF cq.components')
           ->setParameters(array('component' => $component));
```